# Windows UAC do not popup (Access Denied)

Tags: windows, uac, executable-jar

I have made an installer using izpack which is packaged as an executable jar file.

Normally when I double click the jar/installer file the windows 7 UAC box pops up and I grant temporary administrator rights when installing the application (my UAC level is second lowest).

But for some reason this box no longer pops up when I double click the jar file. As a consequence I get an error "Access Denied" when the installer tries to install a windows service (during this process some keys are set in the registration database).

Any ideas on how I get windows to recognize the jar file as an installer and pop up the UAC box as previously?

It works fine if I open cmd in administrator mode and cd to the jar file and run it from there. But it could be nice to make it work the other way (correct way).

Answer (score 2):

Izpack/izpack2exe will [prompt for UAC privilege elevation](http://jpz-log.info/archives/2008/11/10/izpack-installers-with-privileged-permissions/) if you [add the element `<run-privileged/>` to the `<info>` section of the config file](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#the-information-element-info).

Or, [if you name the installation executable to include "setup.exe" or "install.exe", Vista and Win7 should automagically prompt for UAC privs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx). (But this isn't foolproof, as an end-user may download your app and change the name, or if you use a JAR distribution...)

Comment: Yes I already use the run-privileged tag:         <run-privileged condition="izpack.windowsinstall.vista|izpack.windowsinstall.7" />. I have also tried with just  <run-privileged /> but it still does not popup. Have run the installer on another machine so something must be corrupted on the the machine I am using.